# self hosted Invoice ninja v5 app 403 invalid secret

Tags: ios, api, http-status-code-403, secret-key, invoice-ninja

After successful installation of invoice ninja v5

Trying to login in IOS app, I get "**403 invalid secret**"

Tried adding multiple times API_SECRET in .env file by removing and changing code. But nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Figured that you have to download the beta version of IOS from this link

v5 iOS app: [Join the Invoice Ninja v5 beta - TestFlight - Apple](https://testflight.apple.com/join/MJ6WpaXh)